# How to host a Microsoft bot on Ubuntu?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, asp.net-core, bots, botframework

I have written a simple bot via VS 2015+Microsoft Bot Framework.
But it runs on the `.Net Framework` 4.6+.

How do i rebuild it on .net core (asp.net core maybe?) and host it on Ubuntu Server?

Or, can it be run on Mono?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, Microsoft Bot Framework hasn't been ported to dotnetcore. However there is a guide explaining how to use Microsoft Bot Framework on a dotnetcore app using  [Microsoft Bot Connector API – v3.0](https://carlos.mendible.com/2016/09/11/netcore-and-microsoft-bot-framework/)